# boost::multiprecision::cpp_int is being copied then deleted every time I try and print it

Tags: c++, boost, new-operator, boost-multiprecision

When I print a `cpp_int` from Boost, it seems that the entire object is copied.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using std::cout;

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    void *memory = malloc(size);
    cout << "New: " << memory << " " << size << "\n";
    return memory;
}

int main() {
    auto u = new boost::multiprecision::cpp_int("987654321");
    cout << "------\n";
    cout << *u << "\n";
}
```

```
New: 0x23d4e70 32
------
New: 0x23d52b0 31
987654321
```

The confusing thing is that the overload for printing is `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const T&)`, but passing `*u` into a function such as `template <typename T> void cr(const T&) {}` does not show any new memory allocation. I also tried `u->str()` but this also causes a 2nd memory allocation.

I also tried overloading the cout for the `cpp_int`:

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const boost::multiprecision::cpp_int& mpi) {
    return stream << mpi.str();
}
```

but the result was the same. However, I am also surprised that this compiled since I had expected there to already be an overload. My assumption is that I may need to modify something more back-end.

How can I avoid this? I don't want to be copying and then deleting 30+ bytes every time I want to print a `cpp_int`.

If not, switching data type it not out of the question, as long as the interface is similar for minimal refactoring.

Comment: Why are you using a `new` operator here?

Comment: This is just a minimal example (but I'm using `new` in the actual, non-minimal program). Here, it serves no real purpose other than showing that the `new` overload actually works. If done on the stack, it's still the same problem though.

Comment: Note: matching `free` is missing because it didn't seem relevant since I was just trying to show unwanted memory allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you mismatched malloc/new is invoking UB (as ubsan+asan will readily tell you).

```
==32752==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: alloc-dealloc-mismatch (malloc vs operator delete
    #0 0x7fb58c15c407 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-lin
    #1 0x564b19759014 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned
    #2 0x564b1974b8cb in std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) /us
    #3 0x564b1974b8cb in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(s
    #4 0x564b197478f4 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, s
    #5 0x564b19744f74 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, s
    #6 0x564b19741053 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, s
    #7 0x564b19744993 in std::ostream& boost::multiprecision::operator<< <boost::mu
    #8 0x564b1973da5a in main /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:14
    #9 0x7fb58ab85bf6 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6
    #10 0x564b1973d669 in _start (/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/sotest+0x4a669)
```

So let's focus on the claim:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using Int = boost::multiprecision::cpp_int;

int main() {
    Int u("987654321");
    std::cout << u << "\n";
}
```

When we ask clang to follow the overload for `operator<<` it leads us here:

```
template <class Backend, expression_template_option ExpressionTemplates>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const number<Backend, ExpressionTemplates>& r)
{
   std::streamsize d  = os.precision();
   std::string     s  = r.str(d, os.flags());
   std::streamsize ss = os.width();
   if (ss > static_cast<std::streamsize>(s.size()))
   {
      char fill = os.fill();
      if ((os.flags() & std::ios_base::left) == std::ios_base::left)
         s.append(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(ss - s.size()), fill);
      else
         s.insert(static_cast<std::string::size_type>(0), static_cast<std::string::size_type>(ss - s.size()), fill);
   }
   return os << s;
}
```

As you can see the number is taken by const-reference, so no copy is performed. There will be allocations for the buffers (in the `str()` implementation). I don't think the Multiprecision library is going to boast a highly optimized implementation of IO operations.

### Memory Profiling

To see exactly what allocations are done where, I ran a debug build through Massif:

[image]

At the peak, the top allocations are:

```
99.97% (73,759B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->98.54% (72,704B) 0x50DDFA4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
| ->98.54% (72,704B) 0x40108F1: _dl_init (dl-init.c:72)
|   ->98.54% (72,704B) 0x40010C8: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so)
|     
->01.39% (1,024B) 0x58C526A: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
| ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x58D5447: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
|   ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x58D4566: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:759)
|     ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x58D2ABB: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
|       ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x58C6A55: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
|         ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x516675A: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<ch
|           ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x10C85C: std::ostream& boost::multiprecision::operat
|             ->01.39% (1,024B) 0x10B6C6: main (test.cpp:8)
|               
->00.04% (31B) in 1 place, below massif's threshold (1.00%)
```

Sadly somehow I cannot make the threshold < 1% (this might be a documented limit).

What we *can* see is that though the 31B allocation happens somewhere, it is dwarfed by the file output buffer (1024B).

If we replace the output statement by just

```
return u.str().length();
```

you can still witness the 31B allocation, which does NOT match the size of the cpp_int type. Indeed, iff we were to copy THAT:

```
return std::make_unique<Int>(u)? 0 : 1;
```

THEN we see a 32B allocation instead:

```
->00.04% (32B) in 1 place, below massif's threshold (1.00%)
```

It is pretty clear that the cpp_int is not being copied, as makes sense.

Comment: Did some heap profiling to try and prove that the number isn't being copued. The actual allocations are under the reporting threshold, but we **can** deduce that the number is NOT being copied.

Comment: How to avoid the allocation? You can't because the interface is centered around returning a `std::string`. no allocator tweaking afforded. Sorry. You can elect to do some binary serialization based on the limbs manually.